# redirect to a page then beautify domain url in php

Tags: php

I do this to redirect to a page `header('location: ../index.php');`.

But after the redirection my URL became like this somedomain.com/index.php.

How to make it just somedomain.com?

Comment: have you tried `header('location: ../');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php header('location: /'); ?>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful... what happens? does it still redirect to `index.php`? if so, you may want to have a look at your `.htaccess` file, but that's not a php issue then...